# редирект в requests с прокси

Tags: python, python-3.x, proxy, requests

всем привет! вопрос: есть код, пример:

```
r  = requests.get('mysite.com',  allow_redirects=False)
```

False стоит потому что нужно собрать cookies перед редиректом. Все работает, но если использовать прокси при запросе:

```
r  = requests.get('mysite.com',  allow_redirects=False,
                  proxies={'http': 'user:pass@10.10.1.10:3128/'})
```

то видимо из за allow_redirects=False не проходит запрос дальше прокси. как мне и собрать cookies, и все это дело провернуть через прокси?

Comment: Как именно вы используете прокси?

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/178213/andreymal r = requests.get('mysite.com',  allow_redirects=False, proxies = {'http': 'http://user:pass@10.10.1.10:3128/'})

Comment: может можно как то разрешить только первый редирект?

Answer (score 0):

Запросы работают как с прокси так и без. К примеру, проверим работу cookies, используя http://httpbin.org:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import requests

url = 'http://httpbin.org'
with requests.Session() as sess:
    assert sess.get(url+'/cookies').json()['cookies'] == {}
    assert sess.get(url+'/redirect-to?url=/cookies/set?a=1').ok
    assert sess.get(url+'/cookies').json()['cookies'] == {'a': '1'}
    assert sess.get(url+'/cookies',
                    allow_redirects=False).json()['cookies'] == {'a': '1'}
```

cookies возвращаются как без так и с `allow_redirects=False` c/без прокси (код в `__main__.py`):

```
$ python .  # client, no proxy
$ HTTP_PROXY='http://localhost:8080' python .  # client with proxy
```

где локальная proxy запущена, используя [`logging-proxy.py`](https://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/_downloads/logging-proxy.py):

```
$ python logging-proxy.py
```